# How to pass a javascript object to a C# MVC 4 controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4, how do you pass a javascript object to a C# controller in AJAX? 
Finally I tried this but it did not work.

**Javascript Client side:**

```
    var myData = {Propr1: '', Propr2: ''};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        url: '/Home/SubmitMyData',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: alert('Youhou'),
        error: alert('not good')
    });
```

**C# Server side method:**

```
    public ActionResult SubmitMyData(MyParamModel myParam)
    {
        // Do my stuff here with my parameter
        return View();
    }

    public class MyParamModel
    {
        string Prop1 { get; set; }
        string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

My parameter is always null. I tried to change the contentType but it still not work.
Where are my mistakes? I found some posts but I did not find what I did wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx](model binding) would be  helpful to know the basics

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Make sure the property names match between the javascript and the C# model. In your question you had `Propr1` and `Propr2` for the javascript object, but in the C# model you had `Prop1` and `Prop2` (missing the "r").
2. Do not `stringify` the data before sending it, and do not set `dataType` to `json`. MVC can parse just fine with a collection of post parameters without the json serialization in your code.
3. Omit the `contentType`, it is not necessary. WebAPI should autodetect this. You can leave it, but it's extraneous.
4. Make sure the model properties are public.

**Javascript Client side:**

```
    var myData = {Prop1: '', Prop2: ''}; // #1
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: myData, // #2
        url: '/Home/SubmitMyData',
        //contentType: 'application/json', #3
        //dataType: 'json', #2
        success: alert('Youhou'),
        error: alert('not good')
    });
```

**C# Server side method:**

```
    public ActionResult SubmitMyData(MyParamModel myParam)
    {
        // Do my stuff here with my parameter
        return View();
    }

    public class MyParamModel // #4
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a small explination of what was wrong and why your code works?

Comment: I do not think the FromBody attribute appropriate here.  The OP is using MVC 4, not Web API.

Comment: @DavidL thanks for pointing that out, I thought this was a WebAPI question due to the title.

Comment: @danludwig Good point.  Perhaps the OP should adjust the title a bit :).

Comment: Sorry for the title. I tried again and it not worked for me :s
My parameter is still null

Comment: @NioxyBrown no worries I gave it a better title.

Comment: I just found my mistake: I totally forgot to make the properties of my model "public" (my bad, @JLRishe and you wrote it...).
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't have more upvotes... excellent answer

Comment: Thankyou very much @danludwig

Comment: @danludwig Senior Developer in my team forgot to add set and get and that cost me 1 whole day to solve Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The value you pass for the `data` property should be an object, not a string:

```
data: myData,
```

the property names need to match:

```
var myData = { Prop1: '', Prop2: ''};
```

you need to use the `[FromBody]` attribute on your parameter value:

```
public ActionResult SubmitMyData([FromBody] MyParamModel myParam)
```

and the properties on your model type need to be `public`:

```
public class MyParamModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```