# Pass JavaScript object to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net-core

I am trying to pass an object using JavaScript to a controller.

I have used two parameters `_amount` and `_total` but the
values are empty in the controller on postback.
Any ideas why I can't get the values?
Also if I want to get the `_data` which is an object containing different 
values, how will I achieve it?

```
var itemsCart=toys.cart._items;

$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("SuccessView", "Home")',
  type: 'POST',
  data:  itemsCart,
  success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult SuccessView(List<ProductViewModel> products)
  {
    return View();
  }
```

View Model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
  {
    public string _amount { set; get; }
    public string _total { set; get; }
  }
```

And a screenshot of the object from the website:

[image]

Comment: what is the output of this--> `console.log(itemsCart)`

Comment: and missing --> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` in ajax call?

Comment: Is the save as the screenshot that I have uploaded

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829340/how-to-pass-a-javascript-object-to-a-c-sharp-mvc-4-controller) this post says i dont need contentType

Comment: Two things, does your API work from Postman? Secondly have your tries using [FromBody] in your post action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is your parameter is declared as `products`, but your AJAX `data` parameter name did not match with controller action parameter name. Try using this setup instead:

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("SuccessView", "Home")',
     type: 'POST',
     data: { products: itemsCart },
     traditional: true,
     success: function (response) {
         alert(response);
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, throwError) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
     }
});
```

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SuccessView([FromBody] List<ProductViewModel> products)
{
    // do something

    return new JsonResult("OK");
}
```

Note that since your AJAX call defined as `type: POST`, you must apply `[HttpPost]` attribute to the controller action.

Related issue:

[Passing A List Of Objects Into An MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I have added your code and still the products on controller are null

Comment: How about using `traditional: true` without stringify? Since you want to pass an array directly as viewmodel collection, `traditional: true` must be set.

Comment: And remove the JSON.stringify() ?

Comment: Just give a try with `data: { products: itemsCart }` and set `traditional: true` because you want to pass viewmodel collection as array.

Comment: Try replicate the properties contained inside `toys.cart._items` array into `ProductViewModel` and see if it passing the value, or create new array which only contains 2 required properties. As far as I know, to pass JS array into controller action parameter you need to match amount of properties in both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data: { products: itemsCart }
```

with

```
data: ({ products: itemsCart })
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult SuccessView(ProductViewModel products)
  {
    //return View();
  }
```